# Are there any kometz katans in the maftir for parashas zachor

Tags: grammar-dikduk, ki-teitzei, parshat-zachor

Are there any kometz katans in the maftir for parashas zachor?  Anyone who knows or has a tikkun that indicates kometz katans, if you could tell me where the kamatz katans in that maftir are, if there are any, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the only ones are in כׇּל and מִכׇּל.